# Create New User Account in Sharepoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to create a new user account(not admin and not use Active Directory) in Sharepoint 2013 On-premise.

How can I work around for this?

Comment: and how ? CSOM, SSOM, Rest ? C#,VB,Javascript?

Comment: Not programatically, just only on sharepoint Server configruation.